Set up a scala project with gradle in intelij
I'm trying to setup a scala project, just to run some basic code and practise scala and gradle.
What is the best method to setup a scala project with intellij and gradle? I'm currently using:
gradle version 6.6
scala version 2.13
java version 1.8
I want to use groovy DSL
Thanks for any advice
I have gone to the new project window in Intellij. I do not have Gradle included as a build generator in the left-hand panel. When I click on Scala as the language, I get: Build system - sbt or Intellij.
I definitely have the gradle plugin installed as if I choose Java as a language I have the option to use gradle as a build tool.
I have also tried the "gradle init" method in the command line but this only gives the following language options:
Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..5]


Scala IntelliJ plugin simply does not support generating Gradle projects with Scala. Probably because nobody in JetBrains implemented such support. It should let you write a Gradle project by hand and import it though. The lack of Scala template in Gradle is similar issue - Scala community in general uses sbt (and recently also Scala CLI, so neither IJ nor Gradle has an incentive for developing such nice templates.

I'd say that if you just want to practice Scala, you can write a simple project.scala for Scala CLI with Scala version and dependencies, then run scala-cli setup-ide . and finally import the directory with IntelliJ. Otherwise you will be resolving 2 issues at once: learning Scala and learning Gradle's hacks for supporting multiple Scala versions.

There is an existing Issue about this on JetBrains YouTrack.
In a meantime, you can use Gradle to create a Project, as described in its' documentation.
After that IDEA will be able to work with it as with any other Gradle-based Project.
